# ubuntu 14.04 artifacts scren when installing

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

I tried to install ubuntu 14, but after a screen appears that reads "ubuntu" (ubuntu loading), my computer screen artifacts (not visible picture or writing)

computer: proc: amd fx8350, ram : 10GB, VGA : msi ati 7730

Comment: [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) may help.

Comment: you may change the screen brightness. Sometimes screen brightness is set to 0.